# Why is $\frac1{2i}\ln \frac{i-z}{i+z}=\frac i{2}\ln \frac{i+z}{i-z}$ possible with complex logarithm?

Tags: complex-numbers

I stumbled upon something today that I couldn't calculate myself.
On a problem set, I managed to get the answer on the left side of this equation, but for some reason it could be simplified even further.

How do I simplifiy this?

> $$\frac1{2i}\ln \frac{i-z}{i+z}=\frac i{2}\ln \frac{i+z}{i-z}$$

Comment: Hint: $ -\log{x} = \log{\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: The  notation $ \ln $ is not used in the complex plane. You have to define $ \ln$ for this question to make sense. Which branch of logarithm are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that

$$\frac 1i=\frac1i\frac ii =-i$$

and $$-\log A=\log \frac1A$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: @ZackKing You are welcome! Bye

Comment: I don't think this answer makes sense when the branch of logarithm is not specified.